# Slow Angular application when loading page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I'm already seeing this issue for a very long time and searched the web for some solutions but I think I'm not using the correct terminology to identify the problem.

I have the following command in my `package.json` when I run `$ npm start`

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck --proxy-config proxy.dev.json --extract-css --show-circular-dependencies false
```

When I start my application with 'npm start' everything seems to work but after I see 'webpack: Compiled succesfully' it takes a very long time (7-8 seconds) until I actually see a page or my loading screen (a spinner is shown when HTTP calls are occuring).

I'm curious what is happening between the compile being successful and showing the page. After the compile is successful I see a blank page for 7-8 seconds.

Once the page is shown and I navigate to another page through the menu everything is immediately shown. But when I change the URL manually and hit enter it takes 7-8 seconds to load the page.

When this happens I see no activity in my console, network tab or whatever... Anything I could check to identify this 'gap' of no response?

Might be worth mentioning, I don't see this issue when serving the application with Apache after `ng build --prod`.

Angular version 5.2.11
Angular-CLI 1.7.4

Network tab
[image]

Performance tab
[image]

Comment: Why are you using the `--show-circular-dependencies false` flag? If you remove it is your application still as slow?

Comment: Use  Performance tab, in chrome's dev tool. You might be able to identify wether it's parsing the scripts that take a while.

Comment: The dependencies flag was added because there are currently some circular dependency warnings. We should solve these too but I don't think this is the cause of the long loading, removing the flag does not have any impact.

I'll have a look with the Performance tab as @David suggested

Comment: @David I added a screenshot of the Performance tab. I'm not sure what to think about it though, I can just tell a lot of things seem to take a long time. Do you have any feedback on it ?

Comment: It looks like it takes 9 seconds to evaluate main.bundle.js. In AOT mode, since un-used code is removed, it takes less time to execute. I'm not sure why it takes that long though.

Comment: Somehow an idea how I can investigate the long duration further?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63279047/5043867

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious what is happening between the compile being successful and
> showing the page. After the compile is successful I see a blank page
> for 7-8 seconds

Your browser needs to download the bundles of your application which must be large depending on your 7-8 seconds of loading. When you `$ ng serve`, by default you generate the bundles in development mode, which means that the bundles are at their **raw size**, so they must be large in size in comparison to the bundles in production mode.

In production mode `--prod` the bundles are minified so they're small, which means it will take less time to download the bundles.

#### NOTE:

If you want to notice this behavior, in your browser open the console & move to the network tab to see the bundles your browser is downloading & how much time it takes.

Comment: Your answer sounds acceptable to me. Though when looking with the Network tab it seems really a big gap of nothing. See screenshot I added to original post

Comment: That is the time it takes to do runtime compilation. When you use production mode, you use by default AOT mode which means that your modules are already ready to be downloaded. For more information about the AOT compilation  https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: Ok, so then do you have any idea how to improve speed when using JIT in development mode? Someone posted about Lazy Loading earlier but removed his comment, might this help?

Comment: Lazy Loading will help reducing the overall loading time but if you want to reduce more time in JIT mode you need to work on your application architecture ( Loading static modules, check the external libraries (size, performance...  Your index.html, package.json & root.module can help us identify the problem.